# R Shiny: render image from file

Tags: r, shiny

This code should render the image sing.jpg in the /www directory after the countdown finishes. This works rendering normal text but with an image - as I have implemented it - I receive the following error:

> argument 1 (type 'closure') cannot be handled by 'cat'

Why is this?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("do", "Click Me"),
  verbatimTextOutput("eventTimeRemaining")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  EventTime <- reactiveVal()

  observeEvent(input$do,{
    EventTime(Sys.time() + 3)
  })

  output$eventTimeRemaining <- renderText({

    req(input$do)

    timeLeft <- round(difftime(EventTime(), Sys.time(), units='secs'))

    if(timeLeft > 0){
      invalidateLater(1000, session)
      msg <- timeLeft
    } else {

      msg <- renderImage({
        # Return a list containing the filename
        list(src = './sing.jpg')
    }, deleteFile = FALSE)

      }

    msg

  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a separate output in `ui` such as `imageOutput` to show your image. In addition, I would make `timeLeft` a separate `reactive` expression that could be referenced by both `eventTimeRemaining` to show the countdown, as well as `msg` (a separate `output` created).

I was not sure how you wanted to handle the initial condition - I set the default `EventTime` to `Sys.time()` but if you use NULL or don't initialize then would need to check for NULL in `output` and `timeLeft` calculation.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("do", "Click Me"),
  verbatimTextOutput("eventTimeRemaining"),
  imageOutput("msg")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  EventTime <- reactiveVal(Sys.time())

  observeEvent(input$do,{
    EventTime(Sys.time() + 3)
  })

  timeLeft <- reactive({
    tl <- round(difftime(EventTime(), Sys.time(), units='secs'))
    if (tl > 0) {
      invalidateLater(1000, session)
    } 
    tl
  })

  output$eventTimeRemaining <- renderText({
    timeLeft()
  })

  output$msg <- renderImage({
    if (timeLeft() > 0) {
      list(src = '')
    } else {
      list(src = './sing.jpg')
    }
  }, deleteFile = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't show the image for me. It does remove the error though.

Comment: @syntheso - if you remove the `if/else` will it show the image without any condition? If not, perhaps it can't find/access the file?

Comment: No, so I guess that may be the case, but no error. It's in www. I tried a few alternatives, will keep going.

Comment: I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Take a look at the example: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/images.html

Comment: Specifically this part: Sending pre-rendered images with renderImage()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209180/discussion-between-ben-and-syntheso).

Comment: It now works -my working directory was setup incorrectly. Answer accepted.